# mysql trying a select with multiple conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, date, select

I have 2 tables with values like below:

**tbl_users**

```
user_ID      name     
1          somename1   
2          somename2   
3          somename3
```

**tbl_interviews**

```
int_ID     user_ID      answer          date      
 1            1         sometextaba   2012-11-04 
 2            2         sometextxcec  2012-10-05
 3            1         sometextabs   2011-06-04
 4            3         sometextxcfc  2012-11-04
 5            3         sometextxcdn  2012-11-04
```

how can i ask mysql tell me who is the only user in the table above that was interviewed this year but had also another interview in the previous years? the only one is the user with id = 1 (since he had an interview (the int_id 1) this year, but the first interview was in 2011 (int-id 3). )
unfortunately I'm not able even to select them..

Comment: Welcome to SO. what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By joining the table against itself, where one side of the join only includes interviews from this year and the other side only includes previous years, the result of the `INNER JOIN` will be users having both.

Because it doesn't need to rely on any aggregates or subqueries, this method should be extremely efficient.  Especially so, if the `date` column has an index.

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT
  thisyear.user_ID,
  name
FROM
  /* Left side of join retrieces only this year (year=2012) */
  tbl_interviews thisyear
  /* Right side retrieves year < 2012 */
  /* The combined result will elmininate any users who don't exist on both sides of the join */
  INNER JOIN tbl_interviews previous_years ON thisyear.user_ID = previous_years.user_ID
  /* and JOIN in the user table to get a name */
  INNER JOIN tbl_users ON tbl_users.user_ID = thisyear.user_ID
WHERE
  YEAR(thisyear.date) = 2012
  AND YEAR(previous_years.date) < 2012
```

#### [Here is a demonstration on SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ccbbb/1)

Comment: This is the best method! I was too lazy to use JOINs and knowingly relied on below par sub-queries :)

Comment: thanks, this works and keeps me investigating! and i didn't know about sqlfiddle, thanks for that too!

Comment: @razzetto if it worked you should accept the answer by clicking the green tick mark next to top left of the answer. That's the right practice at SO. If you liked the answer, then you can upvote as well.

Comment: You probably missed a distinct or group by in cases where JOINs produce duplicates (if there are more interviews than one in those yrs). No big deal, just said to make your answer perfect.

Answer (score 1):

A simple approach, perhaps less efficient than `JOIN`s

```
SELECT DISTINCT user_ID
FROM   tbl_interviews
WHERE  user_ID IN (
                   SELECT   user_ID
                   FROM     tbl_interviews 
                   WHERE    date < 2012-01-01
                  ) 
   AND user_ID IN (
                   SELECT   user_ID
                   FROM     tbl_interviews 
                   WHERE    date > 2012-01-01
                  )
```

Answer (score 1):

Following gives you the users taking interviews in Current year, only those who also had appeared in some Previous year/s

```
SELECT Distinct tc.user_ID  FROM  tbl_interviews tc
INNER JOIN tbl_interviews tp ON tc.user_ID = tp.user_ID
WHERE YEAR(tc.date) = Year(curDate())  AND YEAR(tp.date) < Year(curDate());
```

[**SqlFiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/93d34/6)

Comment: I had agreed and upvoted Michael Berkowski, with few difference

Comment: He wants if interview had taken place in `previous yrs`, not just the last year..

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version with no joins, and only one subselect.

```
SELECT user_id
FROM (
    SELECT user_id,
           MAX(date) AS last_interview,
           COUNT(int_id) AS interviews
    FROM tbl_interviews
    GROUP BY user_id) AS t
WHERE YEAR(last_interview) = 2012 AND interviews > 1
```

You can group `tbl_interviews` by `user_id` to count the number of interviews per user, and then filter for users who have more than one interview (in addition to having an interview this year). There a number of variations on this theme, according to your specific needs, so let me know if needs a tweak.

For example, this should work as well.

```
SELECT user_id
FROM (
    SELECT user_id,
           BIT_OR(YEAR(date) = 2012) AS this_year,
           BIT_OR(YEAR(date) < 2012) AS other_year
    FROM tbl_interviews
    GROUP BY user_id) AS t
WHERE this_year AND other_year
```

Comment: Your first answer is wrong. Count can be > 1 even if there are two interviews after 2012!

Comment: @razzetto Try the first query in the fiddle link given in the other answer and you will see wrong result.

Comment: @nawfal The first example is different from the second, you're right! It depends on the assumptions you make on the data, e.g. can someone have more than one interview per year? The first count should probably be changed to `SUM(IF(YEAR(date) < 2012, 1, 0)` to ensure that only interviews from previous years are counted.

Comment: @razzetto No hurry, but you should eventually mark one of the answers as correct. Cheers.

Comment: @jmilloy either delete that query or edit it appropriately to avoid the potential downvotes in future